# Is there a base64 encoding for numbers that works like base10 or base2?

Tags: base64

In base2 (binary), the characters to represent each digit are `01`. `0` being the first character of the base2 alphabet, you can prefix any base2 number with as many `0` as you want without changing the meaning of the number.

All of these are equivalent:

```
11
011
0011
00011
```

In base10 (decimal), the characters to represent each digit are `0123456789`. `0` being the first character of the base10 alphabet, you can prefix any base10 number with as many `0` as you want without changing the meaning of the number.

All of these are equivalent:

```
3
03
003
0003
```

In a hypothetical base64, let's assume the characters to represent each digit are `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`. `A` being the first character of the base64 alphabet, you should be able to prefix any base64 number with as many `A` as you want without changing the meaning of the number.

All of these would be equivalent:

```
5+fn
A5+fn
AA5+fn
AAA5+fn
```

I understand that [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) does not work this way because it was not intended to encode numbers but any binary data.

Is there a formal RFC documenting this hypothetical base64 encoding? Are there any implementation in some programming languages?

Comment: I'm not clear what an answer to this question would look like. What would it mean for it to "exist", beyond the fact that you can describe and implement it? It's possible to implement any numeric base, with any set of symbols you want. Are you looking for an implementation of this in a particular language?

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you, I clarified the question.

Comment: Thanks, but it still feels kind of "fluffy" - conversion of a numeric value to a particular written base is just a matter of division and modulo, so the only thing to standardise would be the symbol list. Is there a reason why you think there _might_ be a standard alphabet for a base of 64 in particular? Is there something you're actually trying to achieve that's led you to this question?

Comment: I would like to see my possibilities to store identifiers in a database such as YouTube videos identifiers. Should I store the "base64" id in clear text or convert it back into a binary (or decimal) form beforehand and store it as a number for efficient indexing.

Comment: Storing as clear text would mean `5+fn` and `A5+fn` are 2 different ids but they would be the same if storing the id as number.